# In which program I can generate signal with 3 harmonics 1000Hz frequency?

Tags: audio, editing, signal, audacity

Generate signal with main harmonic - 1000Hz frequency and two other harmonics (second and third) with the same frequency.
I found Audacity but I don't know how to do such there. Help me please.
P.S. I translated text from Russian so it can be a little wrong.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: WINDOWS XP SP3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Audacity 1.3.13-beta:

- Create new file
- Menu > `Generate` > `Tone`
- Pick your fundamental frequency (f = 1000Hz), and any other options you'd like (amplitude, length, etc.)
- Hit Ok - It will generate a 1000Hz tone.
- Menu > `Tracks` > `Add New` > `Audio Track`
- Ensure the new track is selected, Menu > `Generate` > `Tone`
- Pick your first harmonic frequency (2f, 3f, etc.) - Example 2f = 2000Hz
- Hit Ok - It will generate a 2000Hz tone.
- Menu > `Tracks` > `Add New` > `Audio Track`
- Ensure the new track is selected, Menu > `Generate` > `Tone`
- Pick your second harmonic frequency - Example 3f = 3000Hz
- Hit Ok - It will generate a 3000Hz tone.

You can now hit the Play button and hear all three tones at once.

Comment: so tones are harmonics?? Thanx a lot, I will try.

Comment: Sort of -- tones are the sound of a certain frequency at a certain amplitude (the "pitch").  Tones can be harmonics of ("in harmony with") other tones.  Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic because I'm no expert. :)

Comment: The tone is the fundamental frequency and the harmonics are multiples of that fundamental frequency. You can put a strobe on a plucked guitar string and actually see how this happens as the string develops standing waves at 2x, 3x, etc. The above Audacity recipe simulates it, but IRL the amplitudes of the harmonics tend to decrease as they get further from the fundamental frequency. So mixing together tracks with a decreasing volume on each harmonic track might give you a better simulation.